# Как, используя Aspose.Email, получить письма с сервера посредством IMAP без вложений?

Tags: python

Скачиваю большое количество писем через IMAP, используя Aspose.Email (через библиотеку Python). Для ускорения и экономии места хочу ограничить скачивание картинок и прочих вложений. Понимаю, что при сохранении можно ограничиться только текстом, используя настройки save. Однако, догадываюсь, что есть другой способ, чтобы первоначально получать письма без вложений. Вот фрагмент кода:

```
    client = ImapClient(domain, port, username, password)
    client.select_folder("Inbox")
    dataDir=""
    for msgInfo in client.list_messages():
        msg = client.fetch_message(msgInfo.unique_id)
        msg.save(dataDir + msgInfo.unique_id + "_out.msg", aspose.email.SaveOptions.default_msg_unicode)
```

Пробовал менять настройки save, меняя форматы выгружаемых писем (eml,html), некоторые из них дают нужный результат, однако, думаю. что это не совсем правильный подход, так как нужно получать письма в любом формате, не сохраняя вложения.